# Android support library strange theme behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-popupwindow

since last night I'm expecting this weird behavior of my application theme:
Popup menus appear with black background and AlertDialogs with white text color.

[image: Black popup menu background] [image: White text color on alert dialog]

By the way, heres my styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Any idea whats wrong? I just want the popup menu to use the default light theme again and the alert dialog to use a black foreground color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved the problem. I passed the application context to both popup menu and alertdialog builder's constructor. This seems to cause problems with application themes. I simply changed `getApplicationContext()` to `getActivity()` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it is wrong?

PopupWindow background is dark in `Theme.Light`:

```
<style name="Widget.PopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_background_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.PopupWindow</item>
</style>
```

If you want to change it - you need to override popup window style for your theme:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:popupWindowStyle">@style/YourCustomStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="YourCustomStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/your_background</item> 
</style>
```

Alert dialog gets customized in the same way

Comment: hey pavel, thanks for your reply. I created a new project to test out something and there my popup menu background is light gray like I want to have it in my project too.The style also inherits from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, so its not black by default